# multiple animations do not run on using jQuery queue() until applied dequeue(), why so?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**When** I tried calling multiple css animations using jQuery queue() function like this -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.text-hello')
                .addClass('anim-hello-in')
                .delay(1700)
                .queue(function (next) {
                    $('.text-enjoy')
                    .addClass('anim-enjoy-in')
                    .delay(6500)
                    .queue(function (next) {
                        $('.text-hello')
                        .addClass('anim-hello-out');
                        $('.text-enjoy')
                        .addClass('anim-enjoy-out')
                        .delay(100)
                        .queue(function (next) {
                            console.log('entered');
                            $('#receipt')
                            .addClass('anim-receipt-in');
                            next(); //don't forget to dequeue so that the rest of the queue can run
                        });
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
```

All the sequences executed successfully except the last queue function, where I'm printing word 'entered' in console. Neither console executed nor the steps executed written after it.

**BUT** when I added 'dequeue()' in above code (like this below), its executed all animations perfectly,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.text-hello')
                .addClass('anim-hello-in')
                .delay(1700, 'fx1')
                .queue('fx1', function (next) {
                    $('.text-enjoy')
                    .addClass('anim-enjoy-in')
                    .delay(6500,'fx2')
                    .queue('fx2', function (next) {
                        $('.text-hello')
                        .addClass('anim-hello-out');
                        $('.text-enjoy')
                        .addClass('anim-enjoy-out')
                        .delay(100, 'fx3')
                        .queue('fx3', function (next) {
                            console.log('in');
                            $('#receipt')
                            .addClass('anim-receipt-in');
                            next(); //don't forget to dequeue so that the rest of the queue can run
                        }).dequeue('fx3');
                    }).dequeue('fx2');
                }).dequeue('fx1');
        });
    </script>
```

Can someone please explain with an example, why its didn't work before but worked later when added dequeue. As I couldn't understand the meaning of using dequeue here when I've already given the delay.

Comment: better go at this page : https://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 0):

Dequeue (directly or through the `next` callback), has to be called for each queued element, in order for the next item in queue to be processed. The queues are attached to each element, so some of the queues don't interfere with each other. The only time an actual 2nd item is added is in the last queue, which is to `.text-enjoy`. The last call to next() would dequeue the last function, but that function is never entered (waiting in a queue on `.text-enjoy` )

In the first version adding a dequeue after `.addClass('anim-enjoy-out')` would also cause the next in queue to be processed.
For cleanliness, all the queues should be cleared, but hypothetically the short solution of getting the first draft to run would be:

```
.addClass('anim-enjoy-out')
.delay(100).dequeue()
```

A good explanation can be found [here](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/)

---

**edit** For clarity, this is what happens:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.text-hello')                               //<-- text-hello obj
            .addClass('anim-hello-in')
            .delay(1700)
            .queue(function (next) {                   //<--queue on text-hello  (1)
                $('.text-enjoy')                       //<--text-enjoy object
                .addClass('anim-enjoy-in')
                .delay(6500)
                .queue(function (next) {               //<--queue on text-enjoy (1)
                    $('.text-hello')                   //<-- text-hello obj
                    .addClass('anim-hello-out');
                    $('.text-enjoy')                   //<--text-enjoy object
                    .addClass('anim-enjoy-out')
                    .delay(100)
                    .queue(function (next) {           //<--queue on text-enjoy (2)
                        console.log('entered');
                        $('#receipt')
                        .addClass('anim-receipt-in');
                        next(); //don't forget to dequeue so that the rest of the queue can run
                    });
                });
            });
    });
```